# How to work in BDD in Android using Cucumber and Guice

Tags: android, dependency-injection, cucumber, guice, bdd

I have started using Cucumber as BDD testing tool in an already working project.
The project uses Guice as Dependancy Injection module.
I need a working tutorial to show in depth how the 3 work together.

What I know already
Currently, I am able to do BDD testing using Cucumber in an android project without using any Dependancy Injection module.
I have already worked on examples using Cucumber in Android. but they use PicoContainer(a cucumber recommended DI module) in DI.But you cannot use more than 1 DI module in your project.

So overall I want a tutorial where Android, Guice, and Cucumber work together.
If anyone has worked on it before please let me know.

Comment: If you have access to the book 'Cucumber for Java' it has 4 pages of explanations in it about Guice integration. Written by the creator of Cucumber so the source is verified.

Comment: Thanks, @Grasshopper I will look into it and confirm if I can use it directly

Comment: @Grasshopper I tried to implement the steps mentioned and tried to inject a parameter. But how do we mention which AbstractModule instance to be used for maintaining the instances and how to initialize it.

Comment: Sorry I have never tried it just read it once. Here is another link I found -http://cucumber.github.io/api/cucumber/jvm/javadoc/cucumber/api/guice/package-summary.html. Maybe this explains better

Comment: @Grasshopper I have seen the link it points to package summary of  cucumber.api.guice. Currently, I am able to use Guice in my Cucumber tests with some help following the example  [link](https://github.com/rapaul/cucumber-jvm-guice-examples/tree/master/src)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to try this library: https://github.com/mauriciotogneri/green-coffee

You just need to import it and then you will be able to run your tests written in Gherkin. It should not create any problem if you use Guice.